# Qweb how to select records with non-null field

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I have a QWeb report where object `o` is `stock.move(97,99,98,325,326,327)`

so

```
<span t-field="o"/>
```

displays

```
stock.move(97,99,98,325,326,327)
```

In database, from all those `stock.move` elements, only three of them have populated the field `procurement_id`:

```
# select id,procurement_id from stock_move where id in (97,98,99,325,326,327);
 id  | procurement_id
-----+----------------
  97 |
  98 |
  99 |
 325 |             16
 326 |             17
 327 |             18
(6 rows)
```

If I do:

```
<span t-field="o.procurement_id"/>
```

The QWeb report is not generated, probably because we are trying to retrieve a null instance of `procurement.order` (in this case, three null instances).

How can I retrieve just the three existing `procurement.order` instances , i.e. the ones that have populated `procurement_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `mapped` to retrieve the procurements as RecordSet or `filtered` to get a new RecordSet of `stock.move`s with whatever you want to filter.

```xml
<!-- get the procurements -->
<span t-esc="o.mapped('procurement_id')" />

<!-- get the moves with procurements -->
<span t-esc="o.filtered(lambda move: move.procurement_id)" />
```

Comment: I tried `<span t-field="o.filtered(lambda move: move.procurement_id)"/>` and I get:    `o.filtered(lambda move: move
                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Comment: I also tried `<span t-field="o.mapped('procurement_id')" />` and I get `Error to render compiling AST
KeyError: "mapped('procurement_id')"`